# How to read a potentially big file by a string separator, process it and save it to a different file?

Tags: c#

I need to write a converter which reads a file by a string separator, processes each line separately. Then some processing will be done (mainly replace function), so it's important for me to read the whole line fully without cutting it anywhere. In the end I will save all the lines to a new file. The separator consists of the following chars: "}\n\r{".

I've already tried StreamReader and read the file into a buffer. Then I processed each buffered string. The problem is that each line from the file can have a different number of signs, so I can't assume how big the buffer size should be. Because of that sometimes a line from the file is split into two buffers so I can't process it properly.

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            char[] fileContent = new char[bufferSize];

            int charRead = streamReader.Read(fileContent, 0, bufferSize);

            if (charRead == 0)
                throw new Exception("File is empty");

            while (charRead > 0)
            {

                stringBuilder.Append(fileContent, 0, charRead);
                stringBuilder.Replace("\",\"url\":\"", "</method>\n    <url><loc><![CDATA[");

                File.AppendAllText(fileSavePath, stringBuilder.ToString());

                charRead = streamReader.Read(fileContent, 0, bufferSize);

                stringBuilder.Clear();
            }
            File.AppendAllText(fileSavePath, stringBuilder.ToString());
            stringBuilder.Clear();
        }
```

The sample input data below:

```
{"reqId":"aQuThygbyKbueE0lKYVi","level":3,"time":"2018-12-20T13:11:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"100.100.10.10","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"\/index.php","message":"User backend OC\\User\\Database is returning home: "}
{"reqId":"DCBlhhhhhT3aq3gJTYX5","level":2,"time":"2018-12-20T14:15:12+00:00","remoteAddr":"199.199.01.01","user":"--","app":"core","method":"GET","url":"\/index.php\/login","message":"Login failed: (Remote IP: '199.199.01.01')"}
```

Comment: Read the file line by line:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time

Comment: Your current code will fail in the rare case that your target string spans  2 buffers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, it's not one char. For sure it's } and { and something between them, maybe end of line character or something else. Because of that the solution which Brad proposed doesn't work, the condition in while loop ReadLine() != null makes the code to read only the first line from the text file.

Comment: OK, the question was: How literal is "}\n\r{" in your input? is there a `'\'` and an `'n'`  or just one char?

Comment: What type of file is this?  XML, HTML, RTF?

Comment: By \n\r I meant line feed and carriage return. I believe those are used in the text file since each one solution which I try ends up in the first line of the text. The file is simple .txt file which I need to convert to XML format.

Comment: Can you show a small part of the input file?

Comment: {"reqId":"aQuThygbyKbueE0lKYVi","level":3,"time":"2018-12-20T13:11:08+00:00","remoteAddr":"100.100.10.10","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"\/index.php","message":"User backend OC\\User\\Database is returning home: "}
{"reqId":"DCBlhhhhhT3aq3gJTYX5","level":2,"time":"2018-12-20T14:15:12+00:00","remoteAddr":"199.199.01.01","user":"--","app":"core","method":"GET","url":"\/index.php\/login","message":"Login failed: (Remote IP: '199.199.01.01')"}
{"reqI... etc.

Comment: Does anyone know any possible solution for that? I noticed that one reply with helpful comments has been deleted by the author, so I'm back stuck with the stuff.

Comment: [Edit] and add the sample data to the question. Make sure it's accurate, and format as code. What you show now looks like json but has missing `,` between the blocks/lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 is to read separate lines, without loading them all at once. Which is as simple as :

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);  // note: NOT ReadAllLines

foreach(string line in lines)
{
   ...
}
```

If the missing `,` in you sample data is correct then each line is a separate Json document.

Comment: How simple is that! Thanks @Henk Holterman, this is exactly what I needed. I perform parsing using JObject for each line buffered and then write into XML file using XMLWriter. Lack of comma in the input file is correct, so each line is treated as a separate block, which is ok for me.